# data.table: read in valid csv

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a way to use data.table/fread on a csv that will fail on an invalid csv?  e.g. A 3G csv file that has a a few rows with 5 fields instead of 3. If not is there another reasonably fast way of validating it?

Comment: `fread` does fail for me when there are inconsistent columns. Do you have a minimal example where it doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@alistaire's comment hinted that I was using an outdated version of the library, and indeed I was.  Version 1.8.10 reads in the csv with no complaints, but version 1.9.6 fails with an error:

```
Error in fread("~/bad.csv") :
  Expecting 3 cols, but line 929579 contains text after processing all cols
...
```

I'm really happy to have this feature!

Answer (score 3):

I find `readr` a bit better at handling odd files than `fread`. Specify the columns you want, and any others should be discarded on import. For example:

```
library( readr )
input <- read_csv( file = file.path,
                              col_names = c( "date", "time", "data" ),
                              col_types = cols_only(
                                  date = col_character(),
                                  time = col_character(),
                                  data = col_character()
                              ),
                              trim_ws = TRUE
    )
```

NOTE: `readr` will output a warning to tell you that 3 columns were "expected", but more were "found" on certain lines, but it won't fail. `fread` will generally fail for this, even if you add a `select` parameter to specify keeping only the number of columns you need.

Comment: `fread` is extended with a `fill` parameter in the development version. When set to `TRUE`, it will fill the empty spots.

Answer (score 0):

Read it normally, then check the number of fields to see if it's valid or not. After that, you can do your work.